# Where can i download Firmware Reverse Analysis Konsole?

Tags: firmware

where i can download the latest version of FRAK: firmware reverse analysis konsole; i cannot find the link; is anyhere a good example or tutorial of usage?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

It appears as though the tool was never released.

https://code.google.com/archive/p/frak/ has been empty since 2012, and merely points to http://frak.redballoonsecurity.com.

http://frak.redballoonsecurity.com has been down for a while, but the last time it was up merely said, ["FRAK is currently undergoing internal code review for public release."](https://web.archive.org/web/20130830114444/http://frak.redballoonsecurity.com)

You can try to contact the [author](https://www.linkedin.com/in/ang-cui-705a42), though: a@redballoonsecurity.com

Answer (score 1):

OFRAK (Open Firmware Reverse Analysis Konsole) has now been released on https://ofrak.com/ and on [GitHub](https://github.com/redballoonsecurity/ofrak).